# How to run iOS app on simulator using latest Xcode 14?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am following this Udemy course called [iOS & Swift - The Complete iOS App Development Bootcamp](https://www.udemy.com/course/ios-13-app-development-bootcamp/) by Angela Yu. I'm on lesson 23 where I'm supposed to run an app on a simulator. Using Xcode version 14.2 (14C18), when I clicked on the run/play button, I am greeted with this error:

[image]

I clicked on the app name as instructed in the video, but no list of simulators appear unlike in the video. So I click on the area beside it that says "Any iOS device" and click on "add additional simulators".

[image]

I create an iPhone 8 simulator, but see no option to actually use it. It just shows up alongside a list of devices. See screenshot:

[image]

Is there anything I've missed? If it matters, I'm on an M1 Macbook Pro. Or maybe I need to do additional work since I'm using an M1?

Comment: Did you check your minimum deployment target?

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadSalman, I've set it to iOS 11 and I can see the simulators now. Previously it was set to an erroneous value of "1".